# control symmetry property when exporting matrix as Matrix Market format .mtx

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, export, sparse-arrays

For example, I have

```
h = SparseArray@{{0, I}, {-I, 0}}
```

If I export h as matrix market format(.mtx) like

```
ExportString[ h, "MTX"]
```

I got

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate complex skew-symmetric

%Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

2 2 1

2 1    0.0000000000000000E+00   -1.0000000000000000E+00
```

It automatically recognize the symmetry property of h, that is fantastic!! **However, I don't want this**. I want a general coordinate format, like this

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate complex general

%Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

2 2 2

1 2    0.0000000000000000E+00    1.0000000000000000E+00

2 1    0.0000000000000000E+00   -1.0000000000000000E+00
```

On the page of [mtx doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MTX.html), there is very limited documentation, though it says

> Export["file.mtx",expr,elem] creates a Matrix Market file by treating
>   expr as specifying element elem.

I don't know what does it mean by  "specifying element elem". And it also says

> Export["file.mtx",expr,Subscript[opt, 1]->Subscript[val,
>   1],[Ellipsis]] exports expr with the specified option elements taken
>   to have the specified values.

What kind of option is supported?

One the page of [matrix market format](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#MMformat), it says

> Several instances of each of these basic formats are defined. **These
>   are obtained by specifying an arithmetic field for the matrix entries
>   (i.e., real, complex, integer, pattern) and a symmetry structure which
>   may reduce the size of the data file (i.e. general, symmetric,
>   skew-symmetric, Hermitian) by storing nonzero entries only on or below
>   the main diagonal.**

So is it possible control symmetry property when exporting matrix as Matrix Market format .mtx in Mathematica? Or more specifically, just force .mtx output general coordinate format without any symmetry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the option `"MatrixStructure"` to  `"General"`:

```
ExportString[h, "MTX", "MatrixStructure" -> "General"]
```

> %%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate complex general
>   %Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com 
>   2 2 2
>   1 2   0.0000000000000000E+00 1.0000000000000000E+00
>   2 1    0.0000000000000000E+00   -1.0000000000000000E+00

Other possible values are `"Hermitian"`, `"SkewSymmetric"`, and `"Symmetric"`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day! But how to do you know the option name?

Comment: Other other hand, how to set the "field" like real,complex,integer,pattern as said in the matrix market doc, also "representation"

Comment: Admittedly, Mathematica's file format documentations are written in a rather confusing way, being quite different to the rest of the documentation. In the case of the MTX documentation, just replace `Meta-information elements` by `Option`. (I did not know this before; I just gave it a try.)

Comment: As for setting the "field": Just convert the exported matrix within Mathematica, e.g. with: integer2real: `N`, real2complex: add `0. I`, integer2complex: also add `0. I`, complex2real: `Re`; real2integer: `Round`.

Comment: For converting a matrix `A` into a pattern array, you can use `SparseArray @@ {Automatic, Dimensions[A], 
  A["Background"], {1, {A["RowPointers"], A["ColumnIndices"]},
   ConstantArray[Pattern, A["RowPointers"][[-1]]]}}`. I am not sure what you mean by "representation". If you mean converting between the matrix market "Coordinate Format" and the "Array Format": Just apply `Normal` and `SparseArray` before export.

Comment: Oh, my god. I found that though I read the pages for 10 times, but I didn't notice there is an "Elements" cell in the doc!! Maybe it is too similar to "Example", what a shame for me : (

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!

Comment: Well, for pattern array, actually you could use `A["PatternArray"]`

Comment: Oh, my god. I found that though I read the `A["Properties"]` for 10 times, but I didn't notice there is an "PatternArray"!! What a shame for me ;)

Comment: Haha, Interesting comment ;)